# ComboBox selects item when clicking on most bottom pixel

Tags: wpf, combobox

Clicking on the first pixel below a WPF combobox leads to an unwanted item selection, because the mouseup directly selects the item which is currently animated under the mouse cursor.

It depends on the height of the combobox, whether the pixel below is clickable or not (on my machine it was clickable if the comboboxes height is 20, not clickable if its height is 21).

Its very easy to reproduce: click multiple times on the bottom pixel and release the mouse button while the popup is animating (maybe animations must be turned on in windows performance settings...).

Does anyone know if this is a WPF bug or how I can prevent the combobox from doing this ?